# How can I cast application class in FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to cast my class that extends to Application in my MapsActivity which is extends to FragmentActivity. I try `getActivity().getApplication()`but it has error **Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()'** and when I try `getApplication()` only it throw runtime error **java.lang.ClassCastException**. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
ApplicationClassName appCtx = (ApplicationClassName ) getActivity().getApplication();
```

Comment: I already tried that. But it has **Cannot resolve method getActivity()**

Answer (score 0):

```
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) getApplication();
```

Comment: It throws runtime error java.lang.ClassCastException